# Как получить статистику по каждому уровню фактора в data.frame?

Tags: r, group-by, data.frame

Имеем таблицу с результатами по вступительным экзаменам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 384 уровня в одной из факторных переменных.
Хотелось бы получить среднее по какой либо переменной для каждого фактора.Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Вы хотите посчитать среднюю оценку по всем предметам по каждому абитуриенту?

Comment: Дело в том, что переменная с абитуриентами у меня идет как факторная, где каждый абитуриент-отдельный уровень фактора. А я бы хотел подсчитать для каждого уровня(каждого абитуриента) средний балл по переменной V4

Comment: Не думаю, что тут нужно цепляться к тому факторная она или нет. Что поменялось бы, если бы она была не факторная, а строковая ? Внизу про dplyr ответили...

Comment: Испрользуйте, по возможности, текстовое представление вместо изображений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я обычно для этого пользуюсь `dplyr`

что то на подобием

```
df1=group_by(d,V3)
df1=summarise( df1,mean_V5=mean(V4))
```

Answer (score 4):

А еще можно сделать то же самое, что и с помощью `dplyr`, ограничившись использованием стандартных средств:

```
tapply(X = d$V4, INDEX = d$V3, FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Тогда можно вспомнить и про `aggregate` и `by`.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @Batanichek отличный. Добавлю к нему пару штрихов.

Если нужно получить статистику по всем переменным разом, очень полезна функция `summarise_each()` из того же `dplyr`. Кроме того, невероятно удобен оператор `%>%` (piping). Он позволяет производить последовательные операции над одним и тем же датасетом. Итак, код выглядит следующим образом.

```
d.mean <- group_by(d, V3) %>%
        summarise_each(funs = funs(mean))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну и для полноты методов. Вдруг автор вопроса знает SQL. Тогда легче использовать sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
df1 <- sqldf('select v3, avg(v4) from d group by v3')
```

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт о больших объёмах данных или важна производительность вычислений, то целесообразно использовать пакет `data.table`. Решение поставленной задачи при помощи пакета `data.table` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
library(data.table) # загружаем пакет
DT <- setDT(DF) # конвертируем data.frame в data.table
DT[, list(Mean = mean(Var)), by = Group] # рассчитываем среднее по группе
```

Если данные содержат пропущенные значения, не забудьте добавить `na.rm = TRUE` при вызове `mean()`. `list` здесь используется для того, чтобы задать имя для столбца, содержащего выходные данные.